# pg_config executable not found

Tags: python, pip, psycopg2

I am having trouble installing psycopg2. I get the following error when I try to `pip install psycopg2`:

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.

Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH

or specify the full executable path with the option:



    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...



or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build/psycopg2
```

But the problem is `pg_config` is actually in my `PATH`; it runs without any problem:

```
$ which pg_config
/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config
```

I tried adding the pg_config path to the `setup.cfg` file and building it using the source files I downloaded from their website (http://initd.org/psycopg/) and I get the following error message!

```
Error: Unable to find 'pg_config' file in '/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/'
```

But it is actually THERE!!!

I am baffled by these errors. Can anyone help please?

By the way, I `sudo` all the commands. Also I am on RHEL 5.5.

Comment: When you run commands as `sudo`, `$PATH` is changed. Can you please double check your $PATH as root?

Comment: In my case, i run `ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config /usr/sbin/pg_config` and every thing ok!

Comment: I got this error too when i was trying to install to pip3 install psycopg2. So i run brew install postgresql first the run pip3 install psycopg2

Answer (score 1416):

`pg_config` is in `postgresql-devel` (`libpq-dev` in Debian/Ubuntu, `libpq-devel` on Centos/Fedora/Cygwin/Babun.)

Comment: Solved after installing `libpq-dev` on ubuntu lucid(10.04). Thank You in Advance.

Comment: # pg_config
The program 'pg_config' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install libpq-dev

Comment: `pg_config` of postgress.app is at `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/<your version>/bin` (Mac OS X)

Comment: and for windows its in     `ProgramFiles\PostgreSQL\version\bin\`

Comment: It's `libpqxx-devel` on fedora.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev` worked for me on Ubuntu

Comment: on Mac OS X: 'brew install postgresql'

Comment: on Alpine Linux: apk add postgresql-dev

Comment: @robsn libpqxx-devel seems unrelated. `xx` signifies `C++`. The package you are looking for is postgresqlXX-devel, where XX is the version number.

Comment: It may also be here on OSX, if you use the Enterprise installer:
`/Library/PostgreSQL/{VERSION}/bin`

Comment: Awesome it worked after installing  sudo apt-get install libpq-dev    in ubuntu Thanks :)

Comment: Same for openSUSE: `zypper in postgresql-devel`

Comment: Solved for me on OSX Mojave using `brew install postgresql`

Comment: I had to install libpd5-devel on centos 7

Comment: ArchLinux: extra/postgresql-libs

Comment: On armbian which is based on debian apt install libpq-dev worked without issues. Thanks!

Comment: AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Amazon Linux 2: `yum -y install postgresql-devel`

Comment: On CentOS `pg_config` can be in the `postgresql`/`postgresql<version>` packages. And for `pip` to be able to see it, in some cases (`/usr/pgsql-<version>/bin/pg_config`) it must be e.g. added to `PATH`. Although in the recent versions (`pg >= 12`) pgdg seems to have started shipping `pg_config` in `libpq5-devel` as well, in which case it's at `/usr/bin/pg_config`.

Comment: Solved with `sudo apt install libpq-dev` on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: I installed postgresql13-devel in the CentOS 7.9 but still show this error. must I install postgresql-devel? @TilmanBaumann

Comment: For both fedora 35 and 36, `sudo dnf install libpq-devel` installed some packages but didn't work. Running `sudo dnf install libpq5-devel` afterwards is what worked.

Comment: Thank you @BillCheatham. This command worked for me too: 
```sudo apt-get install libpq-dev```

Comment: I am using `amazon-linux` and installing `postgresql-devel` fixed this issue for me.

Comment: This sort of ruines the idea behind `virtualenv` if one tries to setup a contained environment for PostgirSQL development using Python. I guess for people, who would to have such an environment, Anaconda/Miniconda would be a better option.

Answer (score 812):

On Mac OS X, I solved it using the [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) package manager

```
brew install postgresql
```

Comment: Excellent! This solved the problem for me, but newbies should be aware that you need to install the [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) package manager first in order for the `brew` command to work.

Comment: Worked for me also, even though I did the brew install after the pgadmin install.

Comment: Doesn't that install the entire database?

Comment: @zmbq Yes, it will. Instead of installing postgresql and setting up paths, symlinks, etc manually, I would recommend using a package manager such as homebrew.

Comment: I need the extra `brew link postgresql`

Comment: To add to @seane's comment, use **[this walkthrough](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/installing-homebrew-on-os-x-el-capitan-10-11-package-manager-for-unix-apps/)** to install `homebrew`.

Comment: This was what worked for me, thank you a lot. It is important to note that there is indeed an important connection between psycopg2 and postgresql that I was not aware of before this.

Comment: Worked for me! (Mac OS) -- needed to add the following in my `.zshrc` --> `export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Comment: This is still working to this day. Thanks a bunch ! Cheers !

Comment: I did not need to do the extra `brew link`.  Installed `postgresql@14`.

Comment: For Apple silicon (e.g., M1,  M2) use: `arch -arm64 brew install postgresql`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74374419/8877692

Answer (score 393):

Have you installed `python-dev`?
If you already have, try also installing `libpq-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev
```

From the article: [How to install psycopg2 under virtualenv](http://web.archive.org/web/20140615091953/http://goshawknest.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/how-to-install-psycopg2-under-virtualenv/)

Comment: In my computer,I only install the client of Postgresql,So that you must install the libpq-dev and the python-dev.

Comment: Doubtful that python-dev is needed.

Comment: **python3-dev is needed.** Without it I get `Python.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: one more dependency required for this is `apt-get install -y gcc`

Comment: I had `python3-dev` installed but had the same error until I installed `libpq-dev`, thanks!

Comment: if you are using python2.7 install python-dev, if you are using python3.5 python3.5-dev, and so on for other versions of python. For me it was python3.9-dev.

Comment: After upgrading to python 3.9 I have to execute: 
**sudo apt install python3.9-dev**

Comment: on Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon
I did 

`sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev`
`sudo apt get install python3-dev`
and it worked. thanks!

Comment: This command gives me this error:   libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 12.11-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but 14.3-1.pgdg20.04+1 is to be installed

Answer (score 127):

Also on OSX. Installed Postgress.app from http://postgresapp.com/ but had the same issue.

I found `pg_config` in that app's contents and added the dir to `$PATH`.

It was at `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin`. So this worked: `export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH"`.

Comment: @GianlucaLodigiani you can also do this if you dont want to restart the console `PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH" pip install psycopg2`

Comment: Perfect BigSur Apple Silicon Works like a charm. I did add the same to ~/.zshrc so that its always available for me.

Comment: worked on Mac Monterey.

Answer (score 116):

You can install pre-compiled binaries on any platform with `pip` or `conda`:

```
python -m pip install psycopg2-binary
```

or

```
conda install psycopg2
```

Please be advised that the [psycopg2-binary pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/) recommends building from source in production:

> The binary package is a practical choice for development and testing but in production it is advised to use the package built from sources

To use the package built from sources, use `python -m pip install psycopg2`. That process will require several dependencies ([documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#install-from-source)) (emphasis mine):

> - **A C compiler**.
> - The **Python header files**. They are usually installed in a package such as **`python-dev`**. A message such as `error: Python.h: No such file or directory` is an indication that the Python headers are missing.
> - The **libpq header files**. They are usually installed in a package such as **`libpq-dev`**. If you get an `error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory` you are missing them.
> - The **`pg_config` program**: it is usually installed by the **`libpq-dev`** package but sometimes it is not in a `PATH` directory. Having it in the `PATH` greatly streamlines the installation, so try running `pg_config --version`: if it returns an error or an unexpected version number then locate the directory containing the `pg_config` shipped with the right `libpq` version (usually `/usr/lib/postgresql/X.Y/bin/`) and add it to the `PATH`:
>
> ```bash
> $ export PATH=/usr/lib/postgresql/X.Y/bin/:$PATH
> ```
>
> You only need `pg_config` to compile `psycopg2`, not for its regular usage.

> Once everything is in place it’s just a matter of running the standard:
>
> ```
> $ pip install psycopg2
> ```
>
> or, from the directory containing the source code:
>
> ```
> $ python setup.py build
> $ python setup.py install
> ```

Comment: On Ubuntu, I needed to install the libpq-dev library first and then just run the pip install command again: `apt install libpq-dev`

Comment: That solved it on a Mac OS X without needing to install postgresql altogether

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the documentation's recommendation to build from source. I second this suggestion--devs should use the later half of this answer and avoid the pre-packaged binary, even for most development purposes.

Comment: This works for elastic beanstalk

Answer (score 89):

For ubuntu users, this is the solution:

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev
```

It worked for me.

Comment: And on Arch/Manjaro it is `postgresql-libs`

Comment: it wokred for me too. whats the problem here? what is libpq-dev used for?

Comment: @Pfinnn when pip builds the psycopg2 module, it requires libpq-dev to do so. There are probably libraries which psychopg2 depends on -- such as a class for handling connections, perhaps.

Answer (score 57):

On alpine, the library containing `pg_config` is [`postgresql-dev`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=postgresql-dev&branch=&repo=&arch=&maintainer=). To install, run:

```
apk add postgresql-dev
```

Answer (score 53):

This is what worked for me on CentOS, first install:

```
sudo yum install postgresql postgresql-devel python-devel
```

On Ubuntu just use the equivilent apt-get packages.

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-dev python-dev
```

And now include the path to your postgresql binary dir with you pip install, this should work for either Debain or RHEL based Linux:

```bash
sudo PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/ pip install psycopg2
```

Make sure to include the correct path. Thats all :)

Comment: On Ubuntu it's `sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-dev python-dev`, and this worked for me.

Comment: also works on Amazon Linux AMI as of Dec 2016. Also make sure `gcc` is installed and python3-devel.

Comment: On Amazon Linux the first command worked nice.

Answer (score 45):

You have to install **libpq-dev/postgresql-libs**, which is the header files and static library for compiling C programs to link with the libpq library in order to communicate with a PostgreSQL database backend.

On Arch this will run:

```
$ sudo pacman -S postgresql-libs
```

On Debian and Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

On Mac OS X:

```
$ brew install postgresql
```

On Red Hat/CentOS/Fedora:

```
$ sudo yum install postgresql-devel
```

Comment: Upvoted for helpfully explaining the precise cause of the issue.

Answer (score 39):

I had this issue because I didn't had a postgres install. If you have brew install run

```
brew install postgresql
```

This should fix the issue.

Comment: yes, I was updating the django requirement.txt. I was getting above error. It get solved when I installed `arch -arm64 brew install postgresql` for M1 mac

Answer (score 37):

```
apt-get build-dep python-psycopg2
```

Answer (score 36):

Just to sum up, I also faced exactly same problem. After reading a lot of stackoverflow posts and online blogs, the final solution which worked for me is this:

1. PostgreSQL(development or any stable version) should be installed before installing psycopg2.
2. The pg_config file (this file normally resides in the bin folder of the PostgreSQL installation folder) PATH had to be explicitly setup before installing psycopg2. In my case, the installation PATH for PostgreSQL is:

   /opt/local/lib/postgresql91/

so in order to explicitly set the PATH of pg_config file, I entered following command in my terminal:

```bash
PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin/
```

This command ensures that when you try to pip install psycopg2, it would find the PATH to pg_config automatically this time.

I have also posted a full error with trace and its solution on my [blog](http://alirazabhayani.blogspot.com/2013/07/install-psycopg2-on-mac-os-x-pgconfig.html) which you may want to refer. Its for Mac OS X but the pg_config PATH problem is generic and applicable to Linux also.

Comment: for me on OS X the path looked like this `PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: @andi Yea, the installation path of Postgres may differ but the installation recipe for psycopg2 which I mentioned above remains the same. Hope it helped.

Answer (score 36):

You should add python requirements used in Postgres on Ubuntu. Run:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev
```

Answer (score 32):

`sudo apt-get install libpq-dev` works for me on Ubuntu 15.4

Comment: If you use newer Ubuntu, still use aforementioned installation instruction. See [pg_config](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/pg_config.1.html)

Answer (score 25):

On Linux Mint `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev` worked for me.

Answer (score 24):

For those running OS X, this solution worked for me:

1. Install Postgres.app:

http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/

2. Then open the Terminal and run this command, replacing where it says {{version}} with the Postgres version number:

```bash
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/{{version}}/bin
```

e.g.

```bash
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin
```

Comment: Or symlink it to the latest version `sudo ln -s /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_config /usr/local/bin/pg_config`

Comment: On my Mac, I exported the PATH from ~/.zprofile file.

Answer (score 24):

Simply run the following:

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev
```

Fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 22):

UPDATE /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo, [base] and [updates] sections
ADD exclude=postgresql*

```bash
curl -O http://yum.postgresql.org/9.1/redhat/rhel-6-i386/pgdg-centos91-9.1-4.noarch.rpmr  
rpm -ivh pgdg-centos91-9.1-4.noarch.rpm

yum install postgresql  
yum install postgresql-devel

PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/

pip install psycopg2
```

Answer (score 19):

Try to add it to PATH:

```bash
PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/ ./pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: `-bash: cd: /usr/pgsql-x.x/bin/: No such file or directory`

Comment: @pylover, you need to use correct path to you Postgres bin directory. Are you sure that `/usr/pgsql-x.x/bin/` is correct?

Comment: It would also be sufficient just to add the folder where all important `pg_` files live. For postgres.app this path on Mac OS X is `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin`.

`PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin`

Please update your *version** if a new version got released!

Comment: This worked for me on OS X El Capitan: `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.0/bin/`

Answer (score 18):

Ali's solution worked for me but I was having trouble finding the bin folder location. A quick way to find the path on Mac OS X is to open psql (there's a quick link in the top menu bar). This will open a separate terminal window and on the second line the path of your Postgres installation will appear like so:

```bash
My-MacBook-Pro:~ Me$ /Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql ; exit;
```

Your pg_config file is in that bin folder. Therefore, before installing psycopg2 set the path of the pg_config file:

```bash
PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/
```

or for newer version:

```bash
PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin
```

Then install psycopg2.

Comment: Newer docs use the following path: `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin`

Comment: It does seem to move about. `find /usr/local -name 'pg_config'`

Answer (score 17):

I'm going to leave this here for the next unfortunate soul who can't get around this problem despite all the provided solutions. Simply use `sudo pip3 install psycopg2-binary`

Comment: This didn't work for me. Only `brew install postgresql` fixed it.

Comment: You might have to `pip install psycopg2-binary` for me: pip -> python2,  pip3 -> python3. But so long as you got it working, it was one of many solutions!

Comment: Solved my problem when using docker.

Answer (score 16):

You need to upgrade your pip before installing psycopg2. Use this command

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: A more detailed answer could be helpful in most cases.

Comment: this is the solution for me. followed by `pip install psycopg2-binary`. Thx

Answer (score 14):

On MacOS, the simplest solution will be to symlink the correct binary, that is under the Postgres package.

```bash
sudo ln -s /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_config /usr/local/bin/pg_config
```

This is fairly harmless, and all the applications will be able to use it system wide, if required.

Comment: Works for me, did not have to sudo though. Thank you!

Comment: Works for me indeed!

Comment: On macOS 11.01, M1 Chip, creating a symlink worked for me: `sudo ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin/pg_config /usr/local/bin/pg_config`

Answer (score 12):

On Mac OS X and If you are using Postgres App (http://postgresapp.com/):

```bash
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin
```

No need to specify version of Postgres in this command. It will be always pointed to latest.

and do

```
pip install psycopg2
```

P.S: If Changes doesn't reflect you may need to restart the Terminal/Command prompt

[Source](https://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html)

Answer (score 11):

Installing [**python-psycopg2**](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/python-psycopg2/) solved it for me on Arch Linux:

```
pacman -S python-psycopg2
```

Comment: What about Windows?

Comment: @PrathameshMore I don't know, I don't use Windows. Have you tried this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25767749/5660517 ?

Answer (score 10):

The following is only relevant for psycopg2 <= 2.6.2

On Windows,
You may want to install the [Windows port of Psycopg](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/index.2.6.2.html), which is recommended in [psycopg's documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20160730185438/http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html).

Comment: These links do not work anymore.

Comment: The Windows port link is visibly broken (the website seems down).

Answer (score 10):

Just solved the problem in Cent OS 7 by:

```bash
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin
```

make sure your PostgreSql version matches the right version above.

Answer (score 10):

**To those on macOS Catalina using the `zsh` shell who have also installed the [postgres app](https://postgresapp.com/):**

Open your `~/.zshrc` file, and *add* the following line:

```bash
export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH"
```

---

Then close all your terminals, reopen them, and you'll have resolved your problem.

If you don't want to close your terminals, simply enter `source ~/.zshrc` in whatever terminal you'd like to keep working on.

Comment: this works on big sur too.

Answer (score 9):

This was partly suggested before, adding it here for clarity.

From the documentation at https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html.
they suggest running: $ **pip install psycopg2-binary**

That solved the issue for me.

Comment: This should not be used in a production environment

Answer (score 8):

Here, for OS X completeness: if you install PostgreSQL from MacPorts, pg_config will be in `/opt/local/lib/postgresql94/bin/pg_config`.

When you installed MacPorts, it already added `/opt/local/bin` to your PATH.

So, this will fix the problem:

`$ sudo ln -s /opt/local/lib/postgresql94/bin/pg_config /opt/local/bin/pg_config`

Now `pip install psycopg2` will be able to run `pg_config` without issues.

Comment: Thank you for providing a MacPorts-specific answer!  I could not find one, and this worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

run the following command to resolve **pg_config executable** not found:-

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpq-dev
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a lack of answers for windows users. Here is how I solved this issue.

First add the PostgreSQL bin folder into the path variable like this

```bash
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin
```

Substitute `\11\` with your version of Postgres

next run

```
pip install pyscopg2
```

this at least got me to a compiling error.

**Update**: it looks to be an issue with the psycopg2 library and it’s dependencies not playing nice with python 3.8. https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/990

Answer (score 7):

For mac users, extend your path variable to include PostgreSQL like this `export PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/12/bin`.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend that you try to use Postgres.app. (http://postgresapp.com) This way you can easily turn Postgres on and off on your Mac. Once you do, add the path to Postgres to your .profile file by appending the following:

`PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH"`

Only after you added Postgres to your path you can try to install psycopg2 either within a virtual environment (using pip) or into your global site-packages.

Answer (score 6):

sudo yum install postgresql-devel   (centos6X)

pip install psycopg2==2.5.2

Answer (score 6):

For those who don't have `Postgresql` locally installed and wish to run it as a Docker container. You should use `psycopg2-binary`.

Answer (score 5):

a simple solution can be

```
pip install psycopg2==2.7.5
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to add a `psycopg2` dependency in your virtual environment that will allow your python project to connect to your docker or kubernetes pod that's running postgresql separately, on your Mac and are not really interested in installing postgresql on your Mac *just* so that you can get pg_config, here's what you do instead:

Install `psycopg2_binary` as suggested in the error output from the pipenv install and everything will work out just fine.

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure you've experienced the same "problem" i did, therefore I'll offer you the extremely easy solution...

In your case, the actual path that you need to add to $PATH (or as a command param) is:

```
/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config
```

not

```
/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin
```

E.g. if you run the python setup.py script afterwards, you would run it like this:

```
python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config build
```

Probably too late, but still the easiest solution.

LATER EDIT:

Under further test I found out that if you initially add the path to pg_config in the form

```
/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin
```

(without /pg_config after ...../bin) and run the pip install command it will work.

However, if you then decide to follow the indication to run python setup.py, you will have to specify the path with /pg_config after ...../bin, i.e.

```
python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config build
```

Comment: An alternative to adding the pgsql/bin directory to the PATH that I've used a fair bit is to symlink `/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/pg_config` (or whatever it's called on your system) to `/usr/bin/pg_config` - that way it's available in the PATH you've already got.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I managed to install psycopg2

```
$ wget http://initd.org/psycopg/tarballs/PSYCOPG-2-5/psycopg2-2.5.3.tar.gz
$ tar -xzf psycopg2-2.5.3.tar.gz
$ cd psycopg2-2.5.3
$ pip install .
```

Answer (score 4):

Using **postgresql-devel** for redhat/ fedora series resolved the issue.

`yum install postgresql-devel`

Answer (score 4):

```
apt install python3-pip -y
apt install python3.10-venv -y
apt install postgresql -y
apt install libpq-dev python2-dev python2 python-dev-is-python3 -y
```

Comment: The question was posed by a Redhat user. The suggested commands only work on Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: Installing postgresql is not necessary, just with libpq-dev is enough.

Answer (score 3):

for CentOS/RedHat make sure that `/etc/alternatives/pgsql-pg_config` is a non-broken symlink

Answer (score 3):

For MAC users -

After adding the `postgresql` package through HomeBrew, you might have to add the `openssl` path variable -

`export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/`

Then you can again `pip install` the `psycopg2` package which should work.

Answer (score 3):

if you have **recently updated python or changed default python** (let's say from 3.6 to 3.8). The following code

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev   OR    sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

will be installing/working for the previous python version.

so if you want this command to work for the recently updated/changed python version try mentioning that specific version like python3.8 in command like

```bash
sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev
```

try above with following

```bash
pip install wheel
export PATH=/path/to/compiled/postgresql/bin:"$PATH"
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
sudo apt-get install python3.x-dev    **Change x with your version, eg python3.8**
pip install psycopg2-binary
pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: turning the line from `psycopg2` to `psycopg2-binary` seem worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I have really big issue with installation of this library on **Oracle Linux 7.9**. And whatever I was doing I wasn't able to install psycopg2 via pip. So I decide to install it via yum with this command:

```
yum install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/python-psycopg2-2.5.1-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

With this command the psycopg2 was installed and I was able create postgres user, DB via ansible. (I know this is like sixtieth answer but I hope this answer can still help somebody).

Answer (score 2):

On Gentoo You have to execute the following

```
# Install postgresql client libraries
sudo emerge postgresql-base
```

Comment: For me, the issue was that the links that `eselect postgresql set [...]` creates were only partially created / broken.  I `rm`ed the ones that looked related (see `ls /usr/include/*p*g*` and `*p*q*`) and then recreated them with `eselect postgresql set 9.5`.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone experiencing this issue working on a Django application and deploying to AWS, the method described in this tutorial worked for me: https://realpython.com/deploying-a-django-app-and-postgresql-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

Here is the author's explanation for when you get the following error:

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.
```

> The problem is that we tried to install psycopy2 (the Postgres Python bindings), but we need the Postgres client drivers to be installed as well. Since they are not installed by default, we need to install them first.

> eb will read custom .config files from a folder called “.ebextensions” at the root level of your project. These .config files allow you to install packages, run arbitrary commands and/or set environment variables. Files in the “.ebextensions” directory should conform to either JSON or YAML syntax and are executed in alphabetical order.

> The first thing to do is install some packages so that our pip install command will complete successfully. To do this, let’s create a file called .ebextensions/01_packages.config:

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    postgresql93-devel: []
    libjpeg-turbo-devel: []
```

> EC2 instances run Amazon Linux, which is a Redhat flavor, so we can use yum to install the packages that we need. For now, we are just going to install three packages - git, the Postgres client, and libjpeg for Pillow.

Answer (score 2):

The following steps solved the issue for me (ubuntu 18.04)

1. install postgres (refer [this](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) if not installed)
2. install libpq-dev

> sudo apt-get install libpq-dev

Answer (score 2):

For Mac people with bash shell:

`$ nano ~/.bash_profile`
`export PATH="/Library/PostgreSQL/<version>/bin:$PATH"` >> at the end of the file >> save and exit
`source ~/.bash_profile` >> to refresh the changes for the terminal to use

Answer (score 1):

I found that this page provided the best instructions for installing PostgreSQL on my mac and that the pip install command worked perfectly afterwards:

https://www.codefellows.org/blog/three-battle-tested-ways-to-install-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

I got fixed this by running the following command.

```
env LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip install psycopg2
```

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39800677/4270698

Answer (score 1):

For users that face this problem building Docker instance.

```
FROM python:3.9.17-slim-bullseye

RUN  apt-get update
RUN apt-get install git libpq-dev -y

COPY requirements.txt /srv/
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r /srv/requirements.txt

RUN rm -r /srv/
COPY . /srv/
```

if you have *psycopg2==2.7.2*

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mac then make sure you have installed Postgresql in your machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the binary instead, I ran into the issue in dockerizing the application when Django tried to install it as part of its dependencies, to resolve that, I used this setup for requirements.txt where the binary is installed first and then django does not try to install it again:
psycopg2-binary
django
gunicorn