# Trying to install psycopg2==2.6.1 failing due to egg_info?

Tags: python, installation, pip, egg

I'm trying to run the following:

```
 pip install psycopg2==2.6.1
```

And I get the following error:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/var/folders/mk/brv9xsjn14df5th28_k1nphw0000gn/T/pip-build-S1xSB8/psycopg2

Is there anyway to fix this? I've tried upgrading pip and upgrading setup-tools to no avail.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886647/cant-install-via-pip-because-of-egg-info-error should help you

$ [sudo] python ez_setup.py
$ [sudo] easy_install pip
$ [sudo] pip install psycopg==2.6.1

Comment: That did not work either, tried that.

Comment: can you try pip install psycopg2==2.6.1 --no-cache-dir

so that it received the package freshly from server

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with you too earlier.

I strongly suspect it's because you don't have your build dependencies installed.

If you're on Ubuntu, try this:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep python-psycopg2
$ sudo pip install psycopg2==2.6.1
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on Mac

Comment: Have you seen [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866695/install-psycopg2-on-mac-osx-10-9-5-pg-config-pip)? You might need to compile it from source...