# Two results for which -a pg_config, trying to install psycopg2 on Mac

Tags: python, postgresql, pip

I am trying to install pyscopg2 (using pip) on Sierra.

Seems to be a common problem, so I've checked out a handful of other SO answers.  I tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35817509/1052985).

But I still can't install.  My error is

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyscopg2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyscopg2
```

When I run `which -a pg_config`, I get TWO lines:

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin//pg_config
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin/pg_config
```

Which feels wrong.

1\ Is the double pg_config the source of my problem?

2\ If so, how do I correct?

Comment: what is your exact pip statement?..

Comment: pip install pyscopg2