# How to install psycopg2 Python on mac?

Tags: python, psycopg2

I tride to install psycopg2

1. pip install psycopg2
   Result
   -bash: pip: command not found
2. pip install django psycopg2
   Result
   -bash: pip: command not found
3. pip3 install django psycopg2 
   Result

Collecting django
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/b0/2138c31bf13e17afc32277239da53e9dfcce27bac8cb68cf1c0123f1fdf5/Django-2.2.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/1c/6997288da181277a0c29bc39a5f9143ff20b8c99f2a7d059cfb55163e165/psycopg2-2.8.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.

pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
<http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).


----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/w3/c440kx852_ngw54hg111zdmh0000gn/T/pip-install-fck7_ffz/psycopg2/
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install psycopg2 with pg\_config error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35104097/how-to-install-psycopg2-with-pg-config-error)

Comment: Same problem 

sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2
Result :
sudo: apt-get: command not found