# Problem with installing psycopg2 on Mac virtualenv: pg_config executable not found

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to use postgresql with my Django project, and for that I need to install psycopg2 in my virtualenv. I already have Postgresql 12.2 installed. However, when I run `pip install psycopg2`, I get the following error:

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.

    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
```

I already found the pg_config executable at `/Library/PostgreSQL/12/bin/pg_config`, but when I try to add it to the PATH variable using `PATH="/Library/PostgreSQL/12/bin/pg_config:$PATH"`, no success or error message is shown. I have never used the PATH variable before, so I am not sure if I am doing this correctly. When I then try to run `which pg_config`, it still says "pg_config not found", and when I try to install psycopg2 again, it shows the same error message.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install psycopg2 with pg\_config error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35104097/how-to-install-psycopg2-with-pg-config-error)

Comment: install psycopg2-binary as suggested in one of the answers in the above link

Answer (score 2):

Two options

1. Install POSTGRESQL using brew:

   brew install postgresql

OR

2. Install `psycopg2-binary` in your python virtual environment

   pip install psycopg2-binary