# Weird errors installing django-heroku for python

Tags: python, django, heroku, installation, pip

Although I'm not sure it is important, I will prefix by saying that I started working on a Heroku app on my old computer and am continuing on my new one.

After a lot of struggling I finally managed to get the app to build on Heroku, although it didn't run. Perhaps the reason was because Heroku doesn't host static files so I set up an Azure account to do that and made some changes to settings.py and created a custom_azure.py file. After running "git push heroku main" it failed to build because it said that django-heroku was not found.

Running "pip install django-heroku" resulted in a many errors. Then "pip freeze" shows that "django-heroku 0.0.0" is installed. Running "pip install --upgrade django-heroku" resulted in the same errors. It is so long I can't post it here so here's a link to a google doc:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/17eQUC3Zd4YKq1vt4jObSV9s7MzoHjBy7jbfCerMlzT0/edit?usp=sharing

I can't make sense of it.

Comment: Did you read error message regarding pg_config and psycopg2-binary it does clearly state what you need to do

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35104097/how-to-install-psycopg2-with-pg-config-error