# Invalid Token 0644 File Permission Django

Tags: python, django, github

I am trying to get this Django Project to run locally https://github.com/vitorfs/bootcamp

I am following the installation guide 
https://github.com/vitorfs/bootcamp/wiki/Installing-and-Running-Bootcamp

but when I try to migrate I get this error

```
$ pip install psycopg2
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.6.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
    or specify the full executable path with the option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/8l/nwwcj_1d2k5_wf3td439ftfh0000gn/T/pip-build-w76_ywwu/psycopg2/
```

So I tried to remove psycopg2 and migrate it, then I receive FILE PERMISSION 0644 Invalid Token. I did that to try and install psycopg2 using pip.

I am using a virtual env.

Comment: Do you have postgres installed? Looks like you don't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pg\_config executable not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618898/pg-config-executable-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 3, you should provide the token on octals format. In your Django settings.py, change to: `FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644`.

Comment: What is the `o` for?

Comment: o is for Octals. We normally use the Decimal notation, where numbers can go from 0 to 9. In Octals number can go from 0 to 7. For permissions in Python 3 (and Django 2 settings) we need to explicitly declare the number as Octals, puttin an 0o before the number.

Comment: So the `o` is new on Python 3?  Excellent, I just learned something

Comment: Not new on Python 3, can be used on 2.7 too, however for Django 2 settings.py the property FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS expects an octal number, not decimal. Best regards

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was the Python3 REQUIREs the `o`.  While Python2 allowed, so the requirement is new in Python 3.