# Flask Python w/AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Requirements.txt file is invalid

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, psycopg2

I know that this kind of question has been asked before, but I've looked through old questions on stackoverflow and have not been able to figure it out. I'm trying to deploy a basic flask python application, and it keeps saying that my requirements text file is invalid. I've gone ahead and ssh'd into the server and manually installed all the dependencies and that has not worked either. Nothing that I am doing is that exotic - it's a simple CRUD app in python that I just want hosted on my beanstalk account.

If anyone has any idea what is going wrong please let me know.

Here is how I run the command. It says that something goes wrong with the  requirements.txt file and that I should look at the logs.

```
patientplatypus:~/Documents/flask-api-seed:14:19:58$eb create flaskbackendpictureswapper
WARNING: You have uncommitted changes.
Creating application version archive "app-005c-170716_142042".
Uploading pythonflaskbackend2/app-005c-170716_142042.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
Environment details for: flaskbackendpictureswapper
  Application name: pythonflaskbackend2
  Region: us-west-2
  Deployed Version: app-005c-170716_142042
  Environment ID: e-hmyr33yywt
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-2::platform/Python 2.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.4.1
  Tier: WebServer-Standard
  CNAME: UNKNOWN
  Updated: 2017-07-16 19:20:47.177000+00:00
Printing Status:
INFO: createEnvironment is starting.
INFO: Using elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-344677375614 as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
INFO: Created security group named: sg-2a389550
INFO: Created load balancer named: awseb-e-h-AWSEBLoa-ANZNI2JDLPA
INFO: Created security group named: awseb-e-hmyr33yywt-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-TSRZ7NFEO9PV
INFO: Created Auto Scaling launch configuration named: awseb-e-hmyr33yywt-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration-D34TJQKNIY2G
INFO: Environment health has transitioned to Pending. Initialization in progress (running for 17 seconds). There are no instances.
INFO: Created Auto Scaling group named: awseb-e-hmyr33yywt-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-FP37J1KGWQ5U
INFO: Waiting for EC2 instances to launch. This may take a few minutes.
INFO: Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:us-west-2:344677375614:scalingPolicy:eb0a3432-c617-4cc6-8ecc-3ea53d3944fb:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-hmyr33yywt-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-FP37J1KGWQ5U:policyName/awseb-e-hmyr33yywt-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleDownPolicy-1T6IHELOZ2U20
INFO: Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:us-west-2:344677375614:scalingPolicy:68ddfbbd-0216-4e96-b504-6e7a0e33c1ef:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-hmyr33yywt-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-FP37J1KGWQ5U:policyName/awseb-e-hmyr33yywt-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleUpPolicy-1NO08SG61UD89
INFO: Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-hmyr33yywt-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmLow-8ORKXR91M1H9
INFO: Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-hmyr33yywt-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh-3D59KXL01V1B
ERROR: Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.
ERROR: [Instance: i-0221157833a7389b3] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
INFO: Added instance [i-0221157833a7389b3] to your environment.
ERROR: Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.

Alert: An update to the EB CLI is available. Run "pip install --upgrade awsebcli" to get the latest version.
```

So here are my logs:

```
============= i-04efc8ed09f52da91 ==============
-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/error_log
-------------------------------------
[Sun Jul 16 19:01:01.918596 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 3035] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Jul 16 19:01:01.919238 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 3035] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Jul 16 19:01:01.919290 2017] [:warn] [pid 3035] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.10.
[Sun Jul 16 19:01:01.919297 2017] [:warn] [pid 3035] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.12.
[Sun Jul 16 19:01:01.920865 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3035] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 16 19:01:01.920899 2017] [core:notice] [pid 3035] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'



-------------------------------------
/opt/python/log/supervisord.log
-------------------------------------
2017-07-16 18:57:49,485 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2017-07-16 18:57:49,495 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2017-07-16 18:57:49,495 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2017-07-16 18:57:49,495 INFO supervisord started with pid 2952
2017-07-16 18:57:50,497 INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 3035
2017-07-16 18:57:51,594 INFO success: httpd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)



-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/access_log
-------------------------------------




-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-activity.log
-------------------------------------
      writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

      Error: pg_config executable not found.

      Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
      or specify the full executable path with the option:

          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

      ----------------------------------------
  Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-EdxBzZ/psycopg2
  You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  2017-07-16 18:58:20,040 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2017-07-16T18:58:20.046Z] INFO  [3091]  - [Application deployment app-005c-170716_135622@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03deploy.py] : Activity failed.
[2017-07-16T18:58:20.046Z] INFO  [3091]  - [Application deployment app-005c-170716_135622@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Activity failed.
[2017-07-16T18:58:20.046Z] INFO  [3091]  - [Application deployment app-005c-170716_135622@1/StartupStage0] : Activity failed.
[2017-07-16T18:58:20.047Z] INFO  [3091]  - [Application deployment app-005c-170716_135622@1] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application deployment - Command CMD-Startup failed
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.837Z] INFO  [3508]  - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.837Z] INFO  [3508]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.837Z] INFO  [3508]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.838Z] INFO  [3508]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.838Z] INFO  [3508]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-16T19:05:52.152Z] INFO  [3508]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Completed activity.
[2017-07-16T19:05:52.153Z] INFO  [3508]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - stage 0 - Command CMD-TailLogs stage 0 completed
[2017-07-16T19:05:52.153Z] INFO  [3508]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsAfter] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-16T19:05:52.153Z] INFO  [3508]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
[2017-07-16T19:05:52.153Z] INFO  [3508]  - [CMD-TailLogs] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.358Z] INFO  [26657] - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.358Z] INFO  [26657] - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.358Z] INFO  [26657] - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.358Z] INFO  [26657] - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.358Z] INFO  [26657] - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
-------------------------------------
  Collecting Jinja2==2.9.6 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 7))
    Downloading Jinja2-2.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (340kB)
  Collecting MarkupSafe==1.0 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 8))
    Downloading MarkupSafe-1.0.tar.gz
  Collecting marshmallow==2.13.5 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 9))
    Downloading marshmallow-2.13.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (45kB)
  Collecting psycopg2==2.7.1 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 10))
    Downloading psycopg2-2.7.1.tar.gz (421kB)
      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
      running egg_info
      creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
      writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
      writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

      Error: pg_config executable not found.

      Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
      or specify the full executable path with the option:

          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

      ----------------------------------------
  Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-EdxBzZ/psycopg2
  You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  2017-07-16 18:58:20,040 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
 File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2017-07-16T18:58:20.047Z] ERROR [3091]  : Command CMD-Startup failed!
[2017-07-16T18:58:20.047Z] INFO  [3091]  : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"(TRUNCATED)...)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py\", line 541, in check_call\n    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)\nCalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1. \nHook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.","severity":"ERROR","timestamp":1500231500},{"msg":"Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1","severity":"SYSTEM","timestamp":1500231500}]}],"truncated":"true"}
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.831Z] DEBUG [3508]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.832Z] DEBUG [3508]  : Checking if the command processor should execute...
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.833Z] DEBUG [3508]  : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-04efc8ed09f52da91)..
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.833Z] INFO  [3508]  : Command is applicable to this instance (i-04efc8ed09f52da91)..
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.833Z] DEBUG [3508]  : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.833Z] INFO  [3508]  : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.833Z] INFO  [3508]  : Received command CMD-TailLogs: {"execution_data":"{\"aws_access_key_id\":\"ASIAIL6VXEGHE7PJUXPQ\",\"signature\":\"uy3wT4bCDYgRC9r\\\/P9iVP4gU5cA=\",\"security_token\":\"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\",\"policy\":\"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\"}","instance_ids":["i-04efc8ed09f52da91"],"data":"c816a41f-6a59-11e7-a97e-4984248772b9","command_name":"CMD-TailLogs","api_version":"1.0","resource_name":"AWSEBAutoScalingGroup","request_id":"c816a41f-6a59-11e7-a97e-4984248772b9"}
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.833Z] INFO  [3508]  : Command processor should execute command.
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.833Z] DEBUG [3508]  : Storing current stage..
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.834Z] DEBUG [3508]  : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.834Z] DEBUG [3508]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.834Z] DEBUG [3508]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.835Z] DEBUG [3508]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.836Z] INFO  [3508]  : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish", "logstreaming"].
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.837Z] INFO  [3508]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.837Z] INFO  [3508]  : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.837Z] DEBUG [3508]  : Loaded definition of Command CMD-TailLogs.
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.837Z] INFO  [3508]  : Executing CMD-TailLogs
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.837Z] INFO  [3508]  : Executing command: CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.837Z] INFO  [3508]  : Executing command CMD-TailLogs activities...
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.837Z] DEBUG [3508]  : Setting environment variables..
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.837Z] INFO  [3508]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.837Z] DEBUG [3508]  : Running stages of Command CMD-TailLogs from stage 0 to stage 0...
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.837Z] INFO  [3508]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.838Z] DEBUG [3508]  : Loaded 1 actions for stage 0.
[2017-07-16T19:05:51.838Z] INFO  [3508]  : Running 1 of 1 actions: TailLogs...
[2017-07-16T19:05:52.153Z] INFO  [3508]  : Running AddonsAfter for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-07-16T19:05:52.153Z] INFO  [3508]  : Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded!
[2017-07-16T19:05:52.153Z] INFO  [3508]  : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"","returncode":0,"events":[{"msg":"[Instance: i-04efc8ed09f52da91] Successfully finished tailing 5 log(s)","severity":"INFO","timestamp":1500231952153}]}]}
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.352Z] DEBUG [26657] : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.352Z] DEBUG [26657] : Checking if the command processor should execute...
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.354Z] DEBUG [26657] : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-04efc8ed09f52da91)..
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.354Z] INFO  [26657] : Command is applicable to this instance (i-04efc8ed09f52da91)..
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.354Z] DEBUG [26657] : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.354Z] INFO  [26657] : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.354Z] INFO  [26657] : Received command CMD-TailLogs: {"execution_data":"{\"aws_access_key_id\":\"ASIAIH2TVTCC4TALMBQA\",\"signature\":\"zjniIyc3hAI6XGSq8VoH8VK1Mrk=\",\"security_token\":\"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\",\"policy\":\"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\"}","instance_ids":["i-04efc8ed09f52da91"],"data":"eeeb41a5-6a5c-11e7-a794-37eb723f1041","command_name":"CMD-TailLogs","api_version":"1.0","resource_name":"AWSEBAutoScalingGroup","request_id":"eeeb41a5-6a5c-11e7-a794-37eb723f1041"}
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.354Z] INFO  [26657] : Command processor should execute command.
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.354Z] DEBUG [26657] : Storing current stage..
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.354Z] DEBUG [26657] : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.354Z] DEBUG [26657] : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.354Z] DEBUG [26657] : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.356Z] DEBUG [26657] : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.356Z] INFO  [26657] : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish", "logstreaming"].
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.357Z] INFO  [26657] : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.357Z] INFO  [26657] : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.358Z] DEBUG [26657] : Loaded definition of Command CMD-TailLogs.
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.358Z] INFO  [26657] : Executing CMD-TailLogs
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.358Z] INFO  [26657] : Executing command: CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.358Z] INFO  [26657] : Executing command CMD-TailLogs activities...
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.358Z] DEBUG [26657] : Setting environment variables..
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.358Z] INFO  [26657] : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.358Z] DEBUG [26657] : Running stages of Command CMD-TailLogs from stage 0 to stage 0...
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.358Z] INFO  [26657] : Running stage 0 of command CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.358Z] DEBUG [26657] : Loaded 1 actions for stage 0.
[2017-07-16T19:28:25.358Z] INFO  [26657] : Running 1 of 1 actions: TailLogs...
```

So that is a LOT of information, which is almost as bad as too little. However I did see this: `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-EdxBzZ/psycopg2` which suggests that there is a problem with psycopg2 but I haven't found a solution online for it. I'm not sure if there are any more things wrong with this or if there is anything else that I need to do -- I have to admit that I don't really understand the error logs.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: 1 person looked at it and downvoted me to 0? Come on man, don't be a jerk.

Comment: `Error: pg_config executable not found.

      Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
      or specify the full executable path with the option:

          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.` That looks like what you should fix.

Comment: im sorry that doesn't solve my problem - why would i have to create this file, when i dont need it to get my crud app running locally. what is supposed to be in this file?

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618898/pg-config-executable-not-found?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: And, obviously, from the error message, `pg_config` is an executable dependency that didn't get installed properly. It is obvious that that error caused all the errors you mentioned in your post, and is the only one worth talking about.