# How to install libpq-dev for psycopg2 in docker

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, rhel7

I have python application running in docker container based on rhel7-atomic (with python36 installed).
I also have separate docker container with PostgreSQL latest version (11.x).
I need to install psycopg2 package in application container so it could work with PostgreSQL. But psycopg2 has libpq-dev package as dependency (http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#build-prerequisites) and I can't install it.
As I saw on their page (https://pypi.org/project/libpq-dev/) they have package only available for python with version no more than 3.4 and PostgreSQL version 9.x. Of course, I can try to downgrade both python and PostgreSQL in order to try things to work (which I'm not sure will work). And it seems strange to me that libpq-dev packages are so old. Maybe I am missing something? Another way to successfully install psycopg2 package?
I saw solutions for docker containers based on another OS, e.g. [Error: pg_config executable not found when installing psycopg2 on Alpine in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46711990/error-pg-config-executable-not-found-when-installing-psycopg2-on-alpine-in-dock). But it's not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

In case it may be helpful for others here what worked for my case.
I looked through all packages containing `pg_config` and other stuff I needed for `psycopg2` and found out that `postgresql-devel` would be fine. I tried it out and it worked. (Maybe later I will update answer with more details)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to downgrade Python.  I have this working with Ubuntu 18 at the moment.  You need to find out what package contains the libpq library on Red Hat.  According to [this](https://serverfault.com/q/316703/509158) answer, the package you need is `postgresql-libs`.

Comment: I tried to install `postgresql-libs` and it seemed to be successful but `psycopg2` can't find now `pg_config` which should've been installed by `postgresql-libs`. I googled and saw that often `pg_config`'s directory is not added to `PATH`. I tried to find this directory by myself but apparently I can't. Command `find / -name "pg_config"` returns nothing as if there is no such file on server.