# Having issues with installing a package called "dbt" using pip

Tags: python, pip, dbt

I am trying to install the package called "dbt", I get a really long error message.

I googled the problem which lead me to a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618898/pg-config-executable-not-found). Here I tried to filter out those answers which are relevant for me, I am on Windows. I upgraded pip its in the latest version. I tried to install "python-dev-tools" which did not help. I feel a bit stuck. Any suggestions? I add the error message below for reference

Thank you in advance!

The error message:

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\46700\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\46700\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4tzr2bw2\psycopg2\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\46700\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4tzr2bw2\psycopg2\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\46700\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4tzr2bw2\psycopg2\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\46700\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4tzr2bw2\psycopg2\
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating C:\Users\46700\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4tzr2bw2\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\46700\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4tzr2bw2\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\46700\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4tzr2bw2\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\46700\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4tzr2bw2\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\46700\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4tzr2bw2\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.

pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
<http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).

----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Some of the dependencies do not seem to be available for Python 3.8 yet (in this case [`psycopg2`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#prerequisites)). Maybe try your luck with Python 3.7. Or try following the instructions in the error message.

Comment: thank you! I will try that,

Answer (score 4):

To fix this i recommend using pip to install pyscopg2. then run the DBT install again.

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
pip install dbt
```

https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/running-a-dbt-project/using-the-command-line-interface/windows/