# Getting "Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info" while installing requirements in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am getting an error in a Colab notebook while installing from a requirements.txt file for a speech emotion recognition library.

First of all, I am cloning the Github project for speech emotion recognition:

```
git clone https://github.com/marcogdepinto/Django-Emotion-Classification-Ravdess-API.git
```

Then installing the requirements using the following code

```
%pip install utils
%cd /content/Django-Emotion-Classification-Ravdess-API
%pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Then the following error is displayed:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have searched everywhere but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: what version of python are you using?egg_info is a structure used by setup tools that details information about a software package. Usually egg_info errors mean that you have problems with or are missing dependencies.

Comment: python 3.6 i am using.
 i am a beginer and didnot know too much coding in python.
speech emotion recognition project i am making for my final year project and facing these difficulties.

Comment: Have you write this command with special characters?Write this command without special characters.On first write pip install utils.Wait installing.After write this cd /content/Django-Emotion-Classification-Ravdess-API.When you are inside the folder Django-Emotion-Classification-Ravdess-API write pip install -r requirements.txt.

Comment: what os are you using?Windows,Ubuntu?

Comment: i am working on window 10

Comment: have you tried the first i write?

Comment: i did same as you told but still the error is the same

Comment: plz help me dear m very stressed.

Answer (score 2):

You have no choice here, you need to see the logs or a more verbose `pip install` output.

Try the [verbose](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/#cmdoption-v) pip option:

```
!pip install -vvv -r requirements.txt
```

At the end of that *loooong* error message, you'll see the actual problem:

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.

    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).
```

You need to install `pg_config`.

This related post ([pg_config executable not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11618898/2745495)) gives options how to do that based on the platform. Since Google Colab runs on a Linux/Ubuntu-based OS:

```
!apt install libpq-dev
```

Note the `!` instead of `%`.

Test it:

```
!pg_config --version
PostgreSQL 10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
```

Then repeat the installation:

```
%pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Google Colab will require you to restart the runtime after the installation completes. Do so. Then you may do the installation again just to confirm that "*Requirement already satisfied:*".

Do take note that while the installation succeeds, there are some warnings that that Django-Emotion-Classification-Ravdess-API may require packages (in requirements.txt) that are not compatible with Colab's pre-install libraries.