# Why postgres SQL DB is different from other db

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgres I want to know why it is used I know that it is object oriented rdbms but what is the example of requirement of object orient rdbms. And also what are it's characteristics that made this database different ???

Comment: Much too broad for Stack Overflow. This site is for narrowly focused questions on a specific technical topic.

Comment: If you have a new question, **[please post a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)**.  There are already discussions and an accepted answer related to your original question, which won't make sense when you [completely revised the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60123991/2). Make sure to check [pg_config executable not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11618898/2745495) first before deciding to post [that new question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60123991/2).

Comment: Got it ! new to stack overflow thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres is relational database like any other relational databases (MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle). From their begins it has only one ORDBMS feature - [table inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-inheritance.html). In academic era, the Postgres was experimental database where people about prof Stonebraker did same experiments about mixing OOP with RDBMS. But it was 30 year ago. This feature was not enhanced 30 years, and has lot of limits, and usually is not recommended to use this feature (if you don't know very well what do you do).

Last 30 years Postgres was (and is) developed like classic relational database system. Against to other databases, Postgres can be strongly enhanced with extensions - the extensions can carry new types, new functions, new operators, new monitoring possibility, new indexes. It is heritage of academic era too, but it is not Object Oriented feature.