# When I try to install psycopg2 using pip install psycopg2 i get this error. What should I do?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

'''
pip install psycopg2
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.8.5.tar.gz (380 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /opt/anaconda3/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/v8/vk9679rj7m7f03_0hztz3rc80000gn/T/pip-install-d7jzvy68/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/v8/vk9679rj7m7f03_0hztz3rc80000gn/T/pip-install-d7jzvy68/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/v8/vk9679rj7m7f03_0hztz3rc80000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-6sv6r8te
         cwd: /private/var/folders/v8/vk9679rj7m7f03_0hztz3rc80000gn/T/pip-install-d7jzvy68/psycopg2/
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating /private/var/folders/v8/vk9679rj7m7f03_0hztz3rc80000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-6sv6r8te/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing /private/var/folders/v8/vk9679rj7m7f03_0hztz3rc80000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-6sv6r8te/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to /private/var/folders/v8/vk9679rj7m7f03_0hztz3rc80000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-6sv6r8te/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to /private/var/folders/v8/vk9679rj7m7f03_0hztz3rc80000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-6sv6r8te/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file '/private/var/folders/v8/vk9679rj7m7f03_0hztz3rc80000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-6sv6r8te/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.

pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
<https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).

----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
'''

Comment: I can't explain better than the error message `Please add the directory
containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path`

Comment: Put the error message in code format { } for easier legibility

Comment: I couldn't find the executable path because I had some files deleted from the previous user on the machine

Answer (score 6):

You can install the pre-compiled binaries. Please refer to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618898/pg-config-executable-not-found) for more information.

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instruction:
Either you add a directory or you specify the full path with the usage of below option.
Another solution is the setup.cfg

pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
option:

```
python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
```

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

Otherwise just use the command:
pip install psycopg2-binary --> that is also recommended into the message

If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
'psycopg2-binary' package instead.