# How can I install psycops2 in my virtual env?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, web, web-applications

I need to install psycopg2 for connecting postgresql with django.I have tried this command.

```
pip install psycopg2
```

but this message was shown:

```
 Error: pg_config executable not found.

    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).


    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Rafid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oknhhl43\psycopg2\
```

I am new to web development so a detailed solution will be helpful...Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pg\_config executable not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618898/pg-config-executable-not-found)

Comment: Use  answer from Parvathirajan Natarajan as the error message stated:"If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead."

Answer (score 2):

Install pre-compiled binaries and then install `psycopg2`

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Answer (score 0):

The install of `psycopg2` is failing because it cannot find a PostgreSQL executable that it runs to find out config details for the local PostgreSQL installation.

There are two alternatives:

1. Download and install PostgreSQL, make sure it is on the PATH, and rerun `pip install psycopg2`

   You can get PostgreSQL installer for Windows from the [download page](https://www.postgresql.org/download/).
2. Run `pip install psycopg2-binary` instead.

---

Note that the [Psycopg2 installation instructions](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html) state that PostgreSQL is a prerequisite.

However, further down it explains that `pg_config` is only needed at build time.