# psycopg2-binary failing to install in docker container

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Apologies for newbie question. I've tried all of the answers from other questions here but the don't pay off either.

Dockerizing my python/django app with Postgres is proving... daunting.  I'm getting the error "Error: pg_config executable not found." consistently when it starts working through my requirements.txt

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.3-slim-buster
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD ./ /code/
```

...and my requirements.txt...

```
asgiref==3.3.1
Django==3.1.4
psycopg2-binary==2.7.4
pytz==2020.5
sqlparse==0.4.1
django-compressor>=2.2
django-libsass>=0.7
```

and docker-compose.yml

```
v ersion: "3.9"
   
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes: 
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes: 
  pgdata:
```

When I run docker-compose up --build I'm getting this error over and over:

```
Step 6/7 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in e0fd67d2d935
Collecting asgiref==3.3.1
  Downloading asgiref-3.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting Django==3.1.4
  Downloading Django-3.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (7.8 MB)
Collecting psycopg2-binary==2.7.4
  Downloading psycopg2-binary-2.7.4.tar.gz (426 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-fha1c65p/psycopg2-binary/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-fha1c65p/psycopg2-binary/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ewxlxmh6
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-fha1c65p/psycopg2-binary/
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ewxlxmh6/psycopg2_binary.egg-info
    writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ewxlxmh6/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ewxlxmh6/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ewxlxmh6/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ewxlxmh6/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    
    Error: pg_config executable not found.
```

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618898/pg-config-executable-not-found

Comment: Can you show your docker-compose?

Comment: Danizavtz: version: "3.9"
   
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes: 
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes: 
  pgdata:

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the answer was seemingly found in a couple of things in my Dockerfile, but... ultimately... downgrading from Python 3.8 to 3.7 unlocked everything.

```
FROM python:3.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y postgresql 
RUN apt-get install libpq-dev gcc
RUN export PATH=/usr/lib/postgresql/X.Y/bin/:$PATH
RUN apt-get install -y python3-dev
RUN apt-get install -y python3-psycopg2 

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ADD ./ /code/
```