# I am trying to download Django-heroku. But I am getting this Error: pg_config executable not found., how to solve it?

Tags: python, django, heroku

Error:

```
(myvenv) (base) siddhants-MacBook-Air:personal-project siddhantbhargava$ pip install django-heroku
Collecting django-heroku
  Using cached django_heroku-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: dj-database-url>=0.5.0 in ./myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django-heroku) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: whitenoise in ./myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django-heroku) (5.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: django in ./myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django-heroku) (2.2.17)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in ./myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django->django-heroku) (2020.5)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in ./myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django->django-heroku) (0.4.1)
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.8.6.tar.gz (383 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/siddhantbhargava/personal-project/myvenv/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/2n/rlv6c5zn6cbggrbcw65fvbz40000gn/T/pip-install-8opynhmw/psycopg2_6f717d71852848bb86def529de299ce9/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/2n/rlv6c5zn6cbggrbcw65fvbz40000gn/T/pip-install-8opynhmw/psycopg2_6f717d71852848bb86def529de299ce9/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/2n/rlv6c5zn6cbggrbcw65fvbz40000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-q4d5yztd
         cwd: /private/var/folders/2n/rlv6c5zn6cbggrbcw65fvbz40000gn/T/pip-install-8opynhmw/psycopg2_6f717d71852848bb86def529de299ce9/
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating /private/var/folders/2n/rlv6c5zn6cbggrbcw65fvbz40000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-q4d5yztd/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing /private/var/folders/2n/rlv6c5zn6cbggrbcw65fvbz40000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-q4d5yztd/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to /private/var/folders/2n/rlv6c5zn6cbggrbcw65fvbz40000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-q4d5yztd/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to /private/var/folders/2n/rlv6c5zn6cbggrbcw65fvbz40000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-q4d5yztd/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file '/private/var/folders/2n/rlv6c5zn6cbggrbcw65fvbz40000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-q4d5yztd/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    
    Error: pg_config executable not found.
    
    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:
    
        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
    
    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
    
    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
    
    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
    
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pg\_config executable not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618898/pg-config-executable-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install django-heroku # deprecated
```

renamed package from django-heroku to django-on-heroku

```
pip install django-on-heroku # try this one
```

[django-on-heroku PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/django-on-heroku/)