# Can't install psycopg2-binary

Tags: django, centos, psycopg2

I'm trying to install psycopg2-binary (pip3 install psycopg2-binary) inside the virtual environment of my Django project on Centos 7 with preinstalled Postgresql 12 and have the well-known error:

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.
    
    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:
    
        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
    
    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
    
    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
```

I tried to install python3-devel postgresql-libs postgresql-server postgresql-devel postgresql-contrib, but still have this error.

pip3 install psycopg2, pip install psycopg2 - the same problem.

PS The problem was solved via updating pip (pip install --upgrade pip).

Comment: Have you postgres installed and running on your machine ?

Comment: Yes, postgress installed. But I'm a slowpoke )) I used the old version of pip. Just pip install --upgrade pip and everything wonderfully started to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618898/pg-config-executable-not-found This contains the possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

**you can try it this method, is very useful**

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-dev python-dev
```