# Errow while working with django, psycopg file shifting to mac (I WOULD ANSWER MYSELF, IT MAY HELP SOMEONE)

Tags: django, macos

I recently shifted to MAC M2 MONTEREY & one project involved django & my dev env from older system isn't setup here. I got error while installing "psycopg" like this:

```
 Using cached psycopg2-2.8.5.tar.gz (380 kB)
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-install-9wiqe2nr/psycopg2_97efcf6747c249769acdc8430ba4238f/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-install-9wiqe2nr/psycopg2_97efcf6747c249769acdc8430ba4238f/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ap2am61r
     cwd: /private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-install-9wiqe2nr/psycopg2_97efcf6747c249769acdc8430ba4238f/
Complete output (23 lines):
running egg_info
creating /private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ap2am61r/psycopg2.egg-info
writing /private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ap2am61r/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to /private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ap2am61r/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to /private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ap2am61r/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing manifest file '/private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ap2am61r/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

Error: pg_config executable not found.

pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
<https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
==============================================================================
Its beginning of the error, After that its tried to install each previous version of Psycopg 
==============================================================================
```

Searching out for solution, a few things helped me out so here's the answer from my side thinking it may help someone else :)

Comment: The https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html page explains what you need to do to get "pg_config".  Read the section about "Build prerequisites".   And then do what the error message above tells you to do.

Comment: It would be very kind of you to search the internet before posting. Also you should read the error messages carefully in the future, it clearly states that it is missing a binary, so look up the prerequisites for the package you want to use. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618898/pg-config-executable-not-found

Answer (score 0):

I was using virtual environment for python for the project.
Solution steps:

- upgrade pip3 to latest version
- upgrade setup tools with `pip3 install --upgrade setuptools`, check the version with `pip list`
- Also try installing "postgres" with `brew install postgres` on the system not in the virtual env of that project (if you're using one) & you can't add it in requirements.txt (INCASE OF AN AUTOMATED DEPLOYMENT) instead you have to then create a bash script which installs OS dependencies first & then the project dependencies with `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`.

This worked for me.