# pg_config executable error with Airflow Postgres providers package

Tags: postgresql, airflow

Attempting to install postgres providers package from Airflow. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/stable/index.html

But hitting an error when the `psycopg2` dependency.

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.
      
      pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
      containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
      option:
      
          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
      
      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
      
      If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
      'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
      
      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
```

So I found [pg_config executable not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618898/pg-config-executable-not-found) and from the message tried installing psycopg2-binary and adding it to the requirements file but it still throws the same error in my `venv`

How could this be resolved?