# Cannot run pytest-postgresql with psycopg[binary]

Tags: python, postgresql, pytest, psycopg2

I have tried running [pytest-postgresql](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-postgresql/) with a [psycopg[binary]](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/install.html#binary-installation) installation but I get a `pytest_postgresql.exceptions.ExecutableMissingException: Could not found pg_config executable. Is it in systenm $PATH?` error.

I thought the binary installation should cover all the dependencies for psycopg and pytest-postgresql to run, but pytest-postgresql can't find a necessary Postgresql file.

Reproducible example:
`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim

RUN pip install pytest==7.3.2 pytest-postgresql==5.0.0 psycopg[binary]==3.1.12

WORKDIR /tests
COPY test.py .

ENTRYPOINT [ "pytest", "test.py" ]
```

`test.py`:

```
import pytest
import psycopg


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def db_session(postgresql):
    with psycopg.connect(
        f"postgresql+psycopg2://{postgresql.info.user}:"
        f"@{postgresql.info.host}:{postgresql.info.port}"
        f"/{postgresql.info.dbname}"
    ) as conn:
        yield conn


def test_something(db_session):
    assert True
```

Running `docker build . -t test && docker run --rm test` gives me:

```
request = <SubRequest 'postgresql_proc' for <Function test_something>>
tmp_path_factory = TempPathFactory(_given_basetemp=None, _trace=<pluggy._tracing.TagTracerSub object at 0x7f844fd0fcd0>, _basetemp=None, _retention_count=3, _retention_policy='all')

    @pytest.fixture(scope="session")
    def postgresql_proc_fixture(
        request: FixtureRequest, tmp_path_factory: TempPathFactory
    ) -> Iterator[PostgreSQLExecutor]:
        """Process fixture for PostgreSQL.
    
        :param request: fixture request object
        :param tmp_path_factory: temporary path object (fixture)
        :returns: tcp executor
        """
        config = get_config(request)
        postgresql_ctl = executable or config["exec"]
        pg_dbname = dbname or config["dbname"]
        pg_load = load or config["load"]
    
        # check if that executable exists, as it's no on system PATH
        # only replace if executable isn't passed manually
        if not os.path.exists(postgresql_ctl) and executable is None:
            try:
                pg_bindir = subprocess.check_output(
                    ["pg_config", "--bindir"], universal_newlines=True
                ).strip()
            except FileNotFoundError as ex:
>               raise ExecutableMissingException(
                    "Could not found pg_config executable. Is it in systenm $PATH?"
                ) from ex
E               pytest_postgresql.exceptions.ExecutableMissingException: Could not found pg_config executable. Is it in systenm $PATH?

/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytest_postgresql/factories/process.py:104: ExecutableMissingException
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR test.py::test_something - pytest_postgresql.exceptions.ExecutableMissin...
=============================== 1 error in 0.16s ===============================
```

Comment: What are the contents of the $PATH variable for the user that the script is being run as? Can you you run pg_config as that user directly from a shell? You may also want to check out this question if you haven't already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618898/pg-config-executable-not-found

Comment: @opike `echo $PATH` gives me `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`. And no, I cannot run `pg_config`. But isn't this the reason to install `psycopg[binary]? So I wouldn't need these dependencies?

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: @opike I'm running everything with Docker, and the image is described in the question body. The base is `python:3.11-slim`.