# Why docker build isn't platform independent?

Tags: linux, docker, macos, docker-compose, docker-build

I have the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ARG WORK_DIR=my-app

# Create a new directory to keep the project files
RUN mkdir $WORK_DIR

# Copy local contents into container
COPY ./ $WORK_DIR

# Setting newly created directory as PWD
WORKDIR $WORK_DIR

# Installing system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
  # Packages for building python
  build-essential \
  # git CLI
  git

# Installing pip packages
RUN pip install pip -U && pip install psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
```

I built an image from it ***on my Ubuntu machine***, without any issues ([here is the complete build logs](https://pastebin.com/fU2Eave0)).

Now, I tried to build the image from ***another machine, macOS***. Unfortunately, I got some errors

```
$ docker build -f Dockerfile . -t test-img
[+] Building 16.3s (10/10) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                          docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 654B                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.8-slim-buster                                                                                                                                    2.5s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.8-slim-buster@sha256:8799b0564103a9f36cfb8a8e1c562e11a9a6f2e3bb214e2adc23982b36a04511                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 5.16kB                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [2/6] RUN mkdir my-app                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [3/6] COPY ./ my-app                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [4/6] WORKDIR my-app                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [5/6] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y   build-essential   git                                                                                                          10.2s
 => ERROR [6/6] RUN pip install pip -U && pip install psycopg2-binary==2.8.5                                                                                                                                 3.5s 
------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 > [6/6] RUN pip install pip -U && pip install psycopg2-binary==2.8.5:                                                                                                                                            
0.811 Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (23.0.1)                                                                                                                       
0.932 Collecting pip                                                                                                                                                                                              
1.184   Downloading pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)                                                                                                                                                            
1.496      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.1/2.1 MB 6.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00                                                                                                                               
1.536 Installing collected packages: pip
1.536   Attempting uninstall: pip
1.536     Found existing installation: pip 23.0.1
1.583     Uninstalling pip-23.0.1:
1.621       Successfully uninstalled pip-23.0.1
2.090 Successfully installed pip-24.0
2.090 WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
2.719 Collecting psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
2.882   Downloading psycopg2-binary-2.8.5.tar.gz (381 kB)
3.055      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 381.7/381.7 kB 2.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
3.106   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
3.395   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
3.398   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
3.398   
3.398   × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
3.398   │ exit code: 1
3.398   ╰─> [23 lines of output]
3.398       running egg_info
3.398       creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-7ualc3qt/psycopg2_binary.egg-info
3.398       writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-7ualc3qt/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/PKG-INFO
3.398       writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-7ualc3qt/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
3.398       writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-7ualc3qt/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/top_level.txt
3.398       writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-7ualc3qt/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
3.398       
3.398       Error: pg_config executable not found.
3.398       
3.398       pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
3.398       containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
3.398       option:
3.398       
3.398           python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
3.398       
3.398       or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
3.398       
3.398       If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
3.398       'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
3.398       
3.398       For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
3.398       <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
3.398       
3.398       [end of output]
3.398   
3.398   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
3.399 error: metadata-generation-failed
3.399 
3.399 × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
3.399 ╰─> See above for output.
3.399 
3.399 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
3.399 hint: See above for details.
------
Dockerfile:26
--------------------
  24 |     
  25 |     # Installing pip packages
  26 | >>> RUN pip install pip -U && pip install psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install pip -U && pip install psycopg2-binary==2.8.5" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

**Question**: Why the same Dockerfile is working in Linux without any issues but not in macOS?

**Note**: The error showing that pg config is missing and maybe something [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618898/pg-config-executable-not-found) helps to resolve the error. But, that is not what I was originally looking for since the docker (or Dockerfile contents) has to be independent of the host machine and in my case, it is not.

Comment: I think your expectations are wrong. Docker is not platform independent and images for different CPU architectures need to fit the host architecture. If you look at the Python image you use, you can see that there are 4 images with that tag for different platforms. And they are different sizes etc. https://hub.docker.com/_/python/tags?page=1&name=3.8-slim-buster

Comment: The `python` binary from the base image and the C shared library in `psycopg2` will be processor-specific, even if the Python code itself is portable.

Comment: Mine is Apple's M-series chip @Philippe

Comment: If you add `libpq-dev` to your `apt-get install`, then your build should run successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
docker pull --platform linux/amd64 python:3.8-slim-buster

docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t test-img .
```